# Append a class to input cakephp apart of inputDefaults CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, form-helpers, cakephp-2.5

Following http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html. I am able to give class to every form field using `inputDefaults` but now:

**Required:** I want to append the class `(say myClass)` in some particular input to those that are inherited by inputDefaults.

```
'inputDefaults' => array(
     'label' => false,
     'div' => 'form-group',
     'class' => 'col-sm-6 form-control'
 )
```

**Every Input Field**

```
<input type="email" id="LoginEmail" maxlength="100" required="required" placeholder="Email" class="col-sm-6 form-control" name="data[Login][email]" />
```

**If I Try**:

```
echo $this->Form->input("email", array("placeholder" => "Email", "required" => "required", "class" => "myClass"));
```

**I get**

```
 <input type="email" id="LoginEmail" maxlength="100" required="required" placeholder="Email" class="myClass" name="data[Login][email]" />
```

**I want as Follows**

```
 <input type="email" id="LoginEmail" maxlength="100" required="required" placeholder="Email" class="col-sm-6 form-control myClass" name="data[Login][email]" />
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you share full code for that input?

Comment: Can you tell me what else in particular do you need ?

Comment: Try this echo $this->Form->input("email", array("placeholder" => "Email", "required" => "required", "class" => "col-sm-6 form-control"))

Comment: That is very obvious thing, that will be used as a last option by me. I am looking for some standard way of doing this.

Comment: Then you have to modify the helper you are using.

Comment: @AshwaniGoyal as i mentioned you have to modify the helper u are using for this.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to have the default class in a var say `defaultClass = 'col-sm-6 form-control'` and use that on the input defaults, and in your input just join the string, something like `$defaultClass. 'myClass'`

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to use twitter bootstrap with cakephp, you may find already coded form helper from https://github.com/Codaxis/cakephp-bootstrap3-helpers#installation handy

Just alias the `Bs3Helpers.Bs3Form` one to the std `Form` as shown there in the installation section and configure the helper in the bootstrap.php.

Another tip is a bake script template: https://github.com/ptica/BootstrapCake

Comment: I appreciate your help @ptica but I am not making new project but working on existing project i.e. so very complex.

Comment: than @sgt is right:
1) code own helper (as https://github.com/Codaxis/cakephp-bootstrap3-helpers/blob/master/View/Helper/Bs3FormHelper.php#L20) with overloaded `input` method
2) alias it as the Form  as shown  in the installation link above